# EF Initializer with multiple contexts for one database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an existing application with a SQL database that has been coded using a database first model (I create an EDMX file every time I have schema changes).

Some additional development (windows services which support the original application) has been done which uses EF POCO/DbContext as the data layer instead of an EF EDMX file.  No initializer settings were ever configured in the DbContexts, but they never modified the database as the DbSet objects always matched the tables.

Now, I've written a seperate application that uses the existing database but only its own, new tables, which it creates itself using EFs initializer.  I had thought this would be a great time to use EF Code First to handle managing these new tables.  Everything worked fine the first time I ran the application, but now I am getting this error from some of my original EF POCO DbContexts (which never used an initializer).

> The model backing the 'ServerContext' context has changed since the
>   database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update
>   the database

After some investigation, I've discovered that EF compares a hash of its schema with some stored hash in the sql server somewhere.  This value doesn't exist until a context has actually used an initializer on the database (in my case, not until the most recent application added its tables).

Now, my other DbContexts throw an error as they read the now existing hash value and it doesn't match its own.  The EF connection using the EDMX doesn't have any errors.

It seems that the solution would be to put this line in `protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)` in all the DbContexts experiencing the issue

```
Database.SetInitializer<NameOfThisContext>(null);
```

But what if later on I wanted to write another application and have it create its own tables again using EF Code first, now I will never be able to reconcile the hash between this theoretical even newer context and the one that is causing the issue right now.

Is there a way to clear the hash that EF stores in the database?  Is EF smart enough to only alter tables that exist as a DbSet in the current context?  Any insights appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What EF version are you using? EF Code First used to store hash of the SSDL in the `EdmMetadata` table. Then in .NET Framework 4.3 thingh changed a little bit and the EdmMetadata table was replaced by `__MigrationsHistory` table (see [this blog post](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/01/13/ef-4-3-beta-1-what-happened-to-that-edmmetadata-table/) for more details). But it appears to me that what you are really looking after is [multi-tenant migrations](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Multi-tenant%20Migrations) where you can have multiple context using the same database. This feature has been introduced in [EF6](http://entityframework.codeplex.com) - (currently Aplpha2 version is publicly available) Also, note that EdmMetadata/__MigrationHistory tables are specific to CodeFirst. If you are using the designer (Model First/Database First) no additional information is stored in the database and the EF model is not checked whether it matches the database. This can lead to hard to debug bugs and/or data corruption.

Comment: I am currently using 4.4, as it is a .Net 4, not 4.5 project.

Comment: In this case you should have __MigrationHistory table. EF6 does not depend as much on the components in .NET Framework as EF5 did and you should get the same functionality (less async) on both - .NET Framework 4 and .NET Framework 4.5 - including multitenant migrations.

Comment: EF6 depends on the .NET Framework. I have not tried but since .NET Framework 4 is supported on Windows XP EF6 should work as well.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Bounded DB contexts is actually good practice.
eg a base context class, to use common connection to DB, each sub class, uses the
Database.SetInitializer(null); as you suggest.

Then go ahead and have 1 large context that has the "view of the DB" and this context  is responsible for all migrations and ONLY that context shoudl do that.  A single source of truth.

Having multiple contexts responsible for the DB migration is a nightmare I dont think you will solve.
Messing with the system entries created by code first migrations can only end in tears.

Exactly the topic you describe I saw in A julie Lerman video.
Her suggested solution was a single "Migration" context and then use many Bounded DB contexts.

In case you have a pluralsight account:
http://pluralsight.com/training/players/PsodPlayer?author=julie-lerman&name=efarchitecture-m2-boundedcontext&mode=live&clip=11&course=efarchitecture

Comment: Great idea, I'll definitely make use of this.  Unfortunately I think it may not apply to this specific situation in that there is no shared code between these applications, so no place to have one large context.

Comment: Hi Mal, the single Context is for DB migration control only. The individual apps use a smaller context without initializer.  no need to share code. Anyway, you get the point... good luck